# Is it ever useful to apply restrict to a single pointer parameter?

Tags: c, performance, compiler-optimization, restrict

Suppose I have some function which takes only one pointer parameter, doesn't access global variables, and does not generate another pointer in a "fishy" way (i.e. it might take the address of a local but not generate an address or get it from another thread etc.). Does it ever help to mark the pointer with `restrict`, or is it useless? In other words, do compilers treat such pointer parameters as implicitly `restrict`ed?

Also, the same question when the function may use `malloc()` or something similar (so there could maybe, possibly, sort of be a fear of aliasing).

Comment: The `restrict` is used for this purpose exactly. This keyword is *your* declaration that the memory will not be handled in the "fishy" way. Using `restrict` when there is a "fishy" code is lying to compiler, and will lead to unpredictable results..

Comment: Then looks like you used it incorrectly. It is not *making* the compiler to perform the check, it is declaring that *you* will not use the pointers to point the same location, and thus allowing the compiler make this assumption in order to make more optimizations.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I misspoke. I was using it to _indicate_ that different pointer parameters are not aliasing each other. The question is whether that's also meaningful if there's just one pointer, for a relaxed definition of "just one".

Comment: `restrict` is not restricted to parameter types qualifying :) Some local variables can effectively alias it as well. The  most trivial is to just assign it's value to a local pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Isn't that "fair game" for a `restrict`ed pointer? I mean, it's a new aliasing which the compiler can notice when working on that function.

Comment: It might or might not notice. It might to get assigned as a runtime decision rather than compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful if the function in question may also access global variables directly -- putting `restrict` on the pointer tells the compiler that you won't access whatever the pointer points at in any way other than the pointer.  So in particular, any global variables you read or write won't alias with the pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask about the case of not accessing globals, just forgot to mention it. The point is that the compiler might theoretically figure out that a `restrict` is in effect by elimination.